# Light bulbs and switches

Tags: combinatorics

There are 40 light bulbs in a room of a big house and 40 switches at a switchboard close to the entrance, far away from the room and without visual contact with it. Each of the switches corresponds to one light bulb. We can only see the status (on, off) of each light bulb by walking to the room. 
We want to find out which switch is connected to each bulb. What is the minimum number of times we will need to walk to the bulbs room?

I understand that there must be a pattern leaving aside some of the bulbs each time, in a unique way. I assume something having to do with the prime factorisation of 40?

Comment: Are the switches marked "on/off", i.e. do we know if a switch in a given position should turn a bulb on (or off)?

Comment: Do the bulbs get warm when in use?  Are you allowed to check whether they are warm?  If so, you reduce the number of trips.  E.g. you can identify three bulbs in one trip.  Turn on switches 1 and 2 and wait long enough for them to get hot,  Turn off switch 2 and go to look.  The bulb connected to switch 1 will be on, that connected to 2 will be off but warm, that connected to 3 will be off and cold.  Depending on the exact behaviour of the bulbs, and whether you know it, you may be able to do even better.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

If there were $2^n$ bulbs you would need $n$ switchings, so you would need 6 switchings because $40>2^5$

You have to prove that whenever you have more than $2^n$ you need more than n swithcings, and here is a method in 6 steps to discover all 40.

Let switches be $S_1,S_2,...,S_{40}$ and $s(ak+b)$ be switching of all the switches with index $i=ak+b$, where $a,k,b\in Z$

1. $s(2k)$
2. $s(4k)$ and $s(4k-1)$
3. $s(8k)$ and $s(8k-2)$ and $s(8k-1)$ and $s(8k-3)$
4. $s(16k)$ and $s(16k-1)$ and $s(16k-2)$... and $s(16k-7)$
5. $s(32k)$ and $s(32k-1)$ and $s(32k-2)$... and $s(32k-15)$
6. $s(64k)$ and $s(64k-1)$ and $s(64k-2)$... and $s(32k-31)$

EDIT - this what I wrote stands with preposition that all the bulbs were off at the beginning. If it was not the case than you would need one more walk to the room. So n+1, or in this particular case 7 times visiting the room.

If you haven't prove the statement yet, this problem is like assigning a binary number to each bulb and to each switch. So whenever you touch a switch you adding 1 to the array of its bits, and if you skip a switch you adding zero to it. Same for bulbs when it change state you add 1, and if it remains same you add 0. In the end each switch fits bulb with the same binary number.

So for each switch to have a different number you need at least $n$ digits for each of them.

Comment: Thanks for the solution; I must add a clarification: The switch reverses the current status of each bulb (well, this is pretty obvious) but we don't know if the light bulbs are on or off at the beginning. Some of them might be on and some off.

Comment: Djura Marinkov: I don't understand how for example the switch s(8k-2) switches the relative bulb - and also for all numbers. Can you please explain with an example?

Comment: @CarlosLopez it is just a way to distinct them from one to another. As I added later, there is a simpier way to do that, to assign them a binary number. You can assign them their index number minus 1. So to 40th switch you can asign 39 = 100111. Which means you will skip this switch in 2nd and 3rd round, and push it in other rounds. $S_1$ you will not push at all...

Comment: @Djura Marinkov: I am trying to understand your solution. So in practical terms, first of all, how do we switch off all bulbs before we start with step 1? How do we know which switches will switch the bulbs off? Then, assuming that they are all set to "off", how do we start? I suppose we number the switches from 1 to 40 and assign them a binary number, for example we assign 000000 to switch number 1? Then which ones do we switch at the first round and how does this work? This is a great problem and I think it is important we understand the solution in depth!

Comment: @Jason You cannot switch off all the bulbs because you don't know which switch is for which bulb. You can only enter the room before you push any switches and remember the state of all the bulbs. Now in each round you notice if state of a bulb changed, if it did, you assign 1 to it if not assign it 0. And for the other question, yes, assign 000000 to $S_1$, 000001 to $S_2$, 000010 to $S_3$,000011 to $S_4$... So now you know which switch to push in each round, in first round push only those whose first digit is 1, in 2nd round push only those with 2nd digit equal to 1...

Comment: @Djura Marinkov: So you say that we assign a binary number to each of the switches, so 40 is for example 101000. Then in the first round you push only 1, 3, 5 etc (since their first digit is 0)? OK so let's assume that some bulbs changed state (from on to off or vice versa) so for those, we put 1 in the rightmost digit and so on? And then we see which binary bulb number matches which switch?

Comment: @Alex.vollenga That is correct, you can assign digits from left to right or right to left, it isn't matter. But you got the point.